# Show network information using PowerShell? Combox is used for selection

Tags: powershell

I have used combo box if network info is selected and clicked on entered then network info will be showed in text file.

[image]

```
if ($combobox1.Text -eq "Network Info")
{
    foreach ($Computer in $arrComputer)
    {
        $path = "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop"))\Network Info.txt";
        $nwINFO = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
                  Where-Object { $_.IPAddress -ne $null } |
                  Select-Object DNSHostName, Description, IPAddress, IpSubnet,
                      DefaultIPGateway, MACAddress, DNSServerSearchOrder |
                  Format-Table -AutoSize |
                  fl > $path;
        notepad $path;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Scripts runs good, however output is not produce notepad dont shows up neither is produce. pls help

I checked for other parameters like name, firewall setting all working fine but not with network config.

Comment: Does `Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` return output for any given `$Computer`? Is `$arrComputer` populated (i.e. does the loop run at all)? Use a debugger to step through your code and inspect the relevant variables. Or at least add some debug logging to your code, so you can see what it does, if it fails, and where.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers something wrong with the loop i guess when i run 

foreach ($Computer in $arrComputer)
  {
   
   $path = "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop"))\Network Info.txt";
   $nwINFO = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.IPAddress -ne $null } | Select-Object DNSHostName, Description, IPAddress, IpSubnet, DefaultIPGateway, MACAddress, DNSServerSearchOrder | Format-Table -AutoSize | fl > $path; notepad $path;
  }
it works perfect but when i include this in if loop for combobox selection it wont work

Comment: Do `$combobox1.Text` and `$arrComputer` actually have the values you think they do?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers  $combobox1.text takes the values mentioned in "abc"
 to match combo selection item n depending on it enters into if loop.

Comment: I'm aware what your code is supposed to do. Did you verify that the variables **actually have the values you think they do?**

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers yes all seems tobe fine when i run them individually it runs but no output is shown wen i include them in if loop if you have any other method pls help